# separating data using visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

What I want to do is separate the voter status and put it on another `DataGridview` in vb.net.
Example, a student who voted is 5 and student who's not voted yet is 5.

I hope you can help me. thanks in advance.
[image]

Comment: where did the image go?

Comment: You need >=10 reputation point to show image directly. Otherwise, you will need someone else to edit your post to show it to you.

Comment: Also, you should elaborate a bit more of the context. Especially, provide the code you have done so far.

Comment: can you help me? edit my post? so that the image will show

Comment: i dont have any code for that. i just have my database. that i took a picture and post it here but it does not showing

Comment: I did the modification already, you should find the notification somewhere upper right the window now, and click accept or something.

Comment: Plus, you should try your best to survey and make a prototype of what you want then ask the specific issue you face during the implement. we won't just provide you code when the question like this broad.

Comment: okay. i'll do that. thank you very much.